# PL/SQL - INSERT com Select em LOOP

Tags: pl-sql

Estou com problemas para terminar esse bloco.

Tenho que fazer o INSERT da TABELA2 com o SELECT da TABELA1, porém, eu preciso que a cada 1000 linhas rode um COMMIT;

Eu não to conseguindo acertar a linha do INSERT.

Eu sei que vai dar certo se eu fizer assim:

`INSERT INTO TABELA2 VALUES (REC.COLUNA1, REC.COLUNA2...)`

Mas não posso, porque serão várias tabelas diferentes e não posso fazer uma query para cada tabela.

já tentei:

`INSERT INTO TABELA2 VALUES (REC.*)`
`INSERT INTO TABELA2 SELECT * FROM REC`

mas não estou chegando no resultado esperado

```
DECLARE

V_N NUMBER;

BEGIN

V_N:= 0;

FOR REC IN 

(

SELECT * FROM TABELA1

)

LOOP

INSERT INTO TABELA2 ??????

V_N := V_N + 1;

IF V_N >= 1000 THEN 

COMMIT;

V_N := 0;

END IF;

END LOOP;

COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: Seriam duas "TABELA2...1" ou "várias tabelas diferentes" , explique melhor.

Answer (score -3):

Bom, consegui chegar numa solução aqui:

```
DECLARE

TYPE ARRAY IS TABLE OF TABELA2%ROWTYPE;
LINHAS_TBL ARRAY;

CURSOR C IS SELECT * FROM TABELA1;

BEGIN
  OPEN C;
  LOOP
  FETCH C BULK COLLECT INTO LINHAS_TBL LIMIT 1000;

      FORALL I IN LINHAS_TBL.FIRST .. LINHAS_TBL.LAST
        INSERT INTO TABELA2 VALUES LINHAS_TBL(I);

      EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    CLOSE C;
END;
```